# In python I can write myarray[:3] to address elements of a list.Is it possible in javascript or node?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, programming-languages

I just don't find how to "translate" to javascript

Using node 12.9.0.

```
#in python
l = [1,2,3]
l = l[1:] #This is tail
l = l[:: -1] #For some reason this reverses the list
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the "tail":

```
l = l.slice(1);
```

To get the "top":

```
l = l.slice(0, 3); // Equivalent to l = l[:3]
```

To reverse:

```
l = l.reverse();
```